# How to record screen+audio+microphone with RecordRTC

Tags: javascript, recordrtc

I am working on a project where I need the user to be able to record screen, audio and microphone. At the moment I could only make it recognize screen and audio.

First I am capturing the screen and the audio from it and saving it to a variable. And then I am capturing that variable to show the a video component.

```js
invokeGetDisplayMedia(success, error) {
        let displaymediastreamconstraints = {
          video: {
            displaySurface: 'monitor', // monitor, window, application, browser
            logicalSurface: true,
            cursor: 'always' // never, always, motion
          }
        };
        // above constraints are NOT supported YET
        // that's why overridnig them
        displaymediastreamconstraints = {
          video: true,
          audio:true
        };
        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
          navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
        }
        else {
          navigator.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
        }
      },
      captureScreen(callback) {
        this.invokeGetDisplayMedia((screen) => {
          this.addStreamStopListener(screen, () => {
            //
          });
          callback(screen);
        }, function (error) {
          console.error(error);
          alert('Unable to capture your screen. Please check console logs.\n' + error);
        });
      },
       startRecording() {
     
    this.captureScreen(screen=>{
        this.audioStream = audio
        console.log(audio)
      this.video=this.$refs.videoScreen
      this.video.srcObject = screen;
      this.recorder = RecordRTC(screen, {
        type: 'video'
      });
      this.recorder.startRecording();
      // release screen on stopRecording
      this.recorder.screen = screen;
      this.videoStart = true;
    });
     
  },
```

Comment: Do you use this library? https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC
It seems pretty well explained there. Maybe can you go more in detail, where your issue is?

Comment: Yes i do. I was able to capture the screen and the sound of it but I don't know how to capture the microphone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936072/recording-the-web-page-by-using-record-rtc-with-angular  anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by increasing a function where I capture the audio from the microphone

```
captureAudio(success, error) {
           let displayuserstreamconstraints = {
          audio:true
        };
        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(displayuserstreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
         
        }
        else {
          navigator.getUserMedia(displayuserstreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
       
        }
        },
```

And adding a function in the startRecording method

```
startRecording() {
        this.captureAudio((audio) => {
        this.captureScreen(screen=>{
          this.video=this.$refs.videoScreen
          this.audioStream=audio
          this.video.srcObject = screen;
          this.recorder = RecordRTC(screen, {
            type: 'video'
          });
          this.recorder.startRecording();
          // release screen on stopRecording
          this.recorder.screen = screen;
          this.videoStart = true;
        });
        })
      },
```

And adding a function in the stopRecording method

```
   stopRecordingCallback() {
    this.video.src = this.video.srcObject = null;
    this.video=this.$refs.videoScreen
    this.video.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.recorder.getBlob());
    this.recorder.screen.stop();
    this.audioStream.stop();
    this.recorder.destroy();
    this.recorder = null;
    
  },
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936072/recording-the-web-page-by-using-record-rtc-with-angular  can help on this. Thanks